# Prediction of amount of job for the next day

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, prediction

I need to solve the next problem:

I am working in a system where you, as a user, can ask for some request to be attended. To have some idea, it is something like **Uber**: you as a user can, at any time, ask for a car to pick you up.

I have the historic of that requests (time and location) for the last two years and now I want to predict the **amount of "jobs requested" for the next hour, day or week**. I know some machine learning algorithms and procedures, but.

What do you think is the best **way** (or **algorithm**) to tackle this task?

Comment: you may try this [helper page](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/tutorial/machine_learning_map/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

stochastic process markov chain

It is a mathematic method to calculate the probability of changing your current state in future. 
Take a look it could be quite helpful if you want to aproximate the number of job requests.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have data of last 2 years, then using time series would be helpful to figure out any pattern either hourly based or weekly based as per requirement. you can also see if any pattern exist for a particular location in some particular time period. as in case of Uber, how many request are being made in time span of 12 noon to say 3p.m. for last month, that might give us a pattern to be followed in coming days.

I will go with time series(*if some pattern can be figured out).